# Redux-saga, optimal way of handling this close modal flow

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

Imagine there is a modal/dialog open. In that modal there is a save button that dispatches an updateUser action that gets picked up by redux-saga. redux-saga then does the network call. If this network call is successful the modal should automatically close. What would be  the optimal way of doing this with redux-saga?

In redux thunk, we would dispatch the action (promise) and we can then chain a 'then' that handles the modal close when the network call was successful, right there in the component. So me and a colleague were wondering, what would be the optimal way to do this with redux-saga?

Comment: What triggers the modal to show up in the first place? Is it data in application/store state?

Comment: the user opens the modal by clicking a button. This could be done in the store, or in local state. We're wondering what would be optimal, without redux saga, we would keep that 'isModalOpen' in local state. Now it seems like we have to link the modal to our redux store some way or another.

Comment: I would move `isModelOpen` to application state. If anything outside the component needs access to that information, move it up.

Answer (score 2):

My take on it:

- Let's assume the owner of the modal keeps the open/closed state as local state
- Let's also assume that in either case (success or failure) this involves some global state (redux) changes

Now the flow:

- Fire action on button click, your saga does it's job
- "Subscribe" to the changes made in the global state by your saga (in `connect`s `mapStateToProps` attach this piece of state to your props too) in the modal's owner component
- In `componentWillReceiveProps` of the modals owner component watch for these changes in case the modal is open, and update the local open/closed state accordingly